# Loading Third Party Iframe on SharePoint publishing page

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, iframe, page-viewer-web-part, third-party-software

I have a SharePoint Publishing Page in which particularly using an `iframe` to load a HR Portal by [Workday](http://www.workday.com/).

So for that, in my Publishing Page I have simply added `Page Viewer Web Part` and then added `iframe` URL in Web Part property, but it is giving me error as below:

> **This content cannot be displayed in a frame**
>
> To help protect the security of information you enter into this website, the publisher of this content does not allow it to be displayed in a frame.

When I open the `iframe` in new window, it is authenticating the user first and then redirecting to the homepage of the portal. But in `iframe` it is not working properly, instead it is redirecting the page to the Workday portal home page after authentication.

I have found some workaround to change something in `X-FRAME-OPTIONS` option from this [article](http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/The-Content-cannot-be-displayed-in-a-frame-Display-another-SharePoint-WebApplication-inside-an-iFrame-of-our-SharePoint-Site), also found [this](http://www.sharepointblogs.be/blogs/vandest/archive/tags/Excel%20Services/default.aspx), but both of this link explains that Iframe URL is from SharePoint itself but different server. In here I have third party portal which I want to show in SharePoint 2013 publishing page. Any idea how to achieve this?

**Update 1**

After taking look at the Network panel in Developer tools found that `X-FRAME-OPTIONS` was set to `SAMEORIGIN`

[image]

and getting `Response body` as below:

[image]

This shows there has to be something on the `Workday` side.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, so it support if request comes from same origin.. in your case if you try to request `wordays.com` from `xyz.com` it will not work.. and result in `Deny`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with SharePoint.

I believe the site `wordays` returns header `X-Frame-Options:DENY`. Once browser see this, it rejects to display it inside IFrame.

Comment: This means, I cannot have this window as an Iframe. Any possibilities that I can achieve this? Though I don't see any except communicating with `Workday` support team.

Comment: I can't think of any other way other than programmatically requesting the site and then displaying it inside a div. I would recommend contacting support team and give it a go.